# Alternative to Rudin's method to prove Q does not have the least upper bound property

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I came across a proof that that shows that if x is the supremum of the set of rationals such that $x > 0$ and $x^2 < 2$, then $x > 1$ and $x^2 = 2$. This is a similar problem to the beginning of Rudin's famous textbook. The part of this proof that I cannot see how to do is to derive two definitions of h. There are two definitions of h used, one used to prove by contradiction that $x^2$ is not less than 2, and the other to prove by contradiction that $x^2$ is not greater than 2. I cannot see how to derive the equations used for h. There are other ways to define h, but I am trying to specifically derive these definitions so I can follow the rest of the text. Here is how it is written:

Suppose $x \in Q$ and $x$ = supremum of E = $\{q \in Q: q>0$ and $q^2 < 2\}$

Then, $x \ge 1$ and $x^2 = 2$

Pf:

**Showing $x \ge 1$:**

Since $1 \in$ E and $x = sup$ E , $x \ge 1$

**Showing $x^2\ge 2$ (by contradiction):**

Assume $x^2 < 2$. Define $h = min\{\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2-x^2}{2(2x+1)}\}$

Then, if $x^2 < 2$ then $h > 0$

We now prove that $x + h \in E$.

Indeed,

$(x + h)^2 = x^2 + 2xh + h^2 < x^2 + h(2x + 1)$ as $h < 1$.

Hence

$(x + h)^2 \le x^2 + (2 - x^2)\cdot \dfrac{2x + 1}{2(2x+1)}$

$= x^2 + \dfrac{2-x^2}{2} < 2 + \dfrac{2-2}{2} = 2$

Therefore, $x + h \in E$ and $x + h > x$ so x is not an upper bound for E. Therefore, x is not sup(E), which is a contradiction. Hence, $x^2 \ge 2$.

**Showing $x^2\le 2$ (by contradiction):**

We now prove that $x^2 \le 2$.

Suppose $x^2 > 2$. Let $h = \dfrac{x^2-2}{2x}$. Then $h>0$ and $x-h > 0$.  Showing that x - h is an upper bound for E:

We have

$(x - h)^2 = x^2 - 2xh + h^2$

$= x^2 - (x^2 - 2) + h^2$

$= 2 + h^2$

$> 2$.

Thus for all $q \in E$, $q < x-h < x$ so $x$ is not the supremum of E, which contradicts assumption.

Therefore, since as per above $x^2 \ge 2$ and $x^2 \le 2$, we conclude that $x^2 = 2$.

**Question about the above proof**

I follow all of the above and can write the proof in an alternative way with h defined as $1/n$, $n \in N$, but I cannot seem to derive these formulas for h:

$h = min\{\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2-x^2}{2(2x+1)}\}$

and

$h = \dfrac{x^2-2}{2x}$

I am probably making some kind of algebraic error or not seeing an inequality that induces the definitions. Can someone help me derive these definitions/formulas for h in a step by step manner?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So if $x^2 < 2$ we need a $x < y = x+h$ where $y^2 = (x+h)^2 = x^2 +2hx + h^2 < 2$.

And if $x^2 > 2$ we need a $x > y = x-h$ where $y^2 = (x-h)^2 = x^2 -2hx +h^2 < 2$.

We can do these.  If $x^2 < 2$ we just need to find an $h$ where $h < \frac {2-x^2}{2x + h}$.  And if $x^2 > 2$ we just need to find an $h$ where $h < \frac {x^2 -2}{2x-h}$ (assuming $h < \frac x2$).

And if we assume $0 < h < 1$ we can achieve these by:

If $x^2 < 2$, just let $h  < \frac {2-x^2}{2x+1}< \frac {2-x^2}{2x+h}$ (if $x < 1$).  ANd if $x^2 > 2$ let $h \le \frac {x^2-2}{2x} < \frac{x^2-2}{2x+h}$.

....

Now at this point I think the author engaged in overkill.  I think the author felt we *had* to find an exact value for $h$.  They did so for $x^2> 2$ by letting $h = \frac {x^2-2}{2x}$ which in turn is *strictly* less than $\frac {x^2-2}{2x - h}$ (I don't think the author thought about the requirement that $h < \frac x2$ but it's easy to see $h =\frac {x^2-2}{2x} < \frac x2$) so the author felt they were done.  (Although, IMO, we don't *need* an *exact* value of $h$-- just a range of $h$).

For $x^2 < 2$.  So long as we have $h < \min(1, \frac {2-x^2}{2x+1})$, we will be good.  And as for as I would be concerned we would be done. We just let $h$ be any rational number small enough.  But, I think, the author thought we needed to express an exact value of $h$.  We can't have $h = \min(1, \frac {2-x^2}{2x+1})$ as that doesn't satisfy the inequality (actually it *does* if $x\ne 1$ [I'll get to that later]), the author thinks, so the author just divides it in half.  Let $h = \frac 12 \min(1, \frac {2-x^2}{2x+1} = \min(\frac 12, \frac {2-x^2}{2x+1}$).

But I really don't think we had to do that.  For one thing, we don't have to specify *exactly* what $h$ *can* be-- just a range that will make it work.  And for another.  If $h < 1$ then $h = \frac{2-x^2}{2x+1} < \frac{2-x^2}{2x+1}$ so setting $h = \frac {2-x^2}{2x+1}$ will work... so long as $h = \frac {2-x^2}{2x+1} < 1$.... which *will* be the case if $x\ge 1$.